# Where are profile files sourced?

Tags: scripts, startup, .profile

I am setting `PATH` `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my `~/.profile` and expect these variables to bet set system-wide (for my user at least). However, upon inspection I find `PATH` is set correctly but `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` remains unset. I think some other script that is executed after my `~/.profile` is overwriting this variable.

I want to troubleshoot the issue but I am not sure which is the culprit script. In particular, I don't what scripts are executed after logging in and where my `~/.profile` is sourced.

So my question is, what are the scripts being executed after logging in? And where are these scripts sourced exactly?

Comment: Read `man bash`. Did you `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Debug this via `set -x;source .bashrc;set +x`

Comment: ...FILES section.

Comment: I do export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I also checked the manual and it says `~/.profile` is executed last, which doesn't seem to be the case on my system (For example, the paths that `/etc/profile` prepends to `PATH` appear before those prepended by `~/.profile`). So I am now even more unsure why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set.